# Need Help Breaking Up PHP Script / max_execution_time exceeded

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have a PHP script which updates the most popular and trending images on my website. This script is meant to be run by cron job once a day but I believe due to the traffic database (on which it mostly relies) in which the daily statistics for each image are stored, being too large, the script times out. I am on hostgator shared hosting and there is no way to increase the max_execution_time and unfortunately a VPS or dedicated server is just not feasible at this time. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions on what I can do with the following script, or the database (currently over 100mb) to make it run smoothly. Do you think truncating the databse would be a good idea, or would it just mess up important aspects on the image data?

The current script is as follows:

```
<?php 
    $minute = date("i");

//  if($minute=='00') {
        include("../config/config.inc.php"); 
        include("../includes/meme-function.php");

        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `meme_id` FROM `$database1`.`memes`");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $query_b = mysql_query("SELECT `views` FROM `$database2`.`daily_meme_stats` WHERE `meme_id` = '$row[meme_id]' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
            $c=0; $week=0; $month=0;
            while($row_b=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_b)) { 
                if($c<=5) {
                    $week=$week+$row_b['views'];
                }
                $month=$month+$row_b['views'];
            }
            mysql_query("UPDATE `$database1`.`memes` SET `views_day` = '0', `views_week` = '$week', `views_month` = '$month' WHERE `meme_id` = '$row[meme_id]' LIMIT 1");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$database2`.`daily_meme_stats` SET `meme_id` = '$row[meme_id]', `date` = '$date'");
        }

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `character_id` FROM `$database1`.`characters`");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $query_b = mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `$database2`.`daily_char_stats` WHERE `char_id` = '$row[character_id]' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
            $c=0; $week=0; $month=0;
            while($row_b=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_b)) { 
                if($c<=5) {
                    $week=$week+$row_b['images'];
                }
                $month=$month+$row_b['images'];
            }
            mysql_query("UPDATE `$database1`.`characters` SET `images_today` = '0', `images_week` = '$week', `images_month` = '$month' WHERE `character_id` = '$row[character_id]' LIMIT 1");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$database2`.`daily_char_stats` SET `char_id` = '$row[character_id]', `date` = '$date'");
        }

//  }
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or ideas you may have.

Comment: Do you save your photos in the database, because a 100mb database is quite large.

Comment: Try running separating the two sql queries. Keep them in two different files and run the both as cron jobs one after the other.

Comment: I'm suspicious of the secondary queries inside the while loops. Depending on the results of the first query these could be running XXXXXX times.

Comment: @GideonAppoh Thanks, no images are saved in the database, only stats such as views.today,views week, views month etc.

Comment: @Vishwa Do you have a recommended file structure including opening and closing tags for each of these files. Perhaps I can give it a try.

Comment: @BigScar Thanks for your response, any suggested modifications? I didn't code the file but It used to do what it was supposed to, perhaps when the database was smaller.

Comment: The current columns within the traffic database are  stat_id , meme_id,  views, and date

Comment: The site has 2 databases, one called main for general info on the images, and one which stores traffic info (stats) btw, I believe the site uses both to operate, and believe this script may call to both, but I suspect the traffic database is the issue due to its large size.

Comment: 1) Change these two blocks into one function that you call twice. The code for each block is virtually identical. 2) What are the indexes on the daily_char_stats and daily_char_stats table and how many rows do they have? Have you done an `EXPLAIN` on your select queries?

Comment: Do you have proper indexes on all columns you are referencing in `WHERE` and `ORDER`? If not, might speed you up a fair bit if you had. ... Do quote your `$array['` **keys** `']`, now you are referencing some of them as if they were constants.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm not exactly sure how to execute your first suggestion, but for the second the 1st query yields  
1  SIMPLE  memes  index  NULL PRIMARY  4  NULL 25065  Using index

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm not exactly sure how to execute your first suggestion, but for the second  suggestion the 1st block yields  
1  SIMPLE  memes  index  NULL PRIMARY  4  NULL 25065  Using index and 1  SIMPLE  daily_meme_stats  ref  meme_id,meme_id_2  meme_id  4  const  1  Using where; Using filesort  for the 2 select queries.


The second block yields SIMPLE  characters  index  NULL PRIMARY  4  NULL 1165  Using index and the query after that SIMPLE  daily_char_stats  ref  char_id,char_id_2  char_id  4  const  1  Using where; Using filesor

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have substituted $database1 and 2 for teh actual database names, and the queries for update and insert retun a syntax error when i try to run the explain query on them. Would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @MarkusAO Hi, not sure how exactly to check that. Please check my above comments, they may provide some information. Regards

Comment: Post the output of the queries `show create table daily_meme_stats;` and `show create table daily_char_stats;` into your question so we can see how the tables are defined.

Comment: I'm on HostGator too, and when I do a PHP cron job, it doesn't time out. Make sure you're running a cron job from the command line -- did you set it up in cPanel?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks Alex, the first returns daily_meme_stats  CREATE TABLE `daily_meme_stats` (
 `stat_id` int(...  and the second returns daily_char_stats  CREATE TABLE `daily_char_stats` (
 `stat_id` int(...  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BradzTech Thanks Bradz, do you mind sharing what command line you are using. Is it usr/bin/php /path and have you defined a php version in your php settings for the directory?

Comment: I'm actually just doing `php www/page/cron.php >> www/page/output.txt`, and no I have never changed php.ini.

Comment: @BradzTech you mean php domain.com/cron.php for example?

Comment: No the command is run from your SSH root. /www will bring you to your site's public HTML directory, which is equivalent to http://domain.com/cron.php

Answer (score 1):

My ideas:

- the first thing which comes to my mind is: try to split the two main queries into their own files.

  - `update-memes.php`, `update-chars.php`
- maybe raise `max_execution_time` a bit or disable it `set_time_limit(0);`

  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php
- maybe move the functionality over to a MySQL stored function
- move all stats (re)calculations into a task/job queue, like Gearman

  - that would work continously in the background and do the updates

---

> Do you have a recommended file structure including opening and closing tags for each of these files.

You have problems splitting the file? Here we go:

`update-memes.php`

```
<?php 
    // set_time_limit(0);

    include '../config/config.inc.php'; 
    include '../includes/meme-function.php';

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `meme_id` FROM `$database1`.`memes`");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $query_b = mysql_query("SELECT `views` FROM `$database2`.`daily_meme_stats` WHERE `meme_id` = '$row[meme_id]' ORDER BY `date` DESC");

        $c=0; $week=0; $month=0;

        while($row_b=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_b)) { 
            if($c<=5) {
                $week=$week+$row_b['views'];
            }
            $month=$month+$row_b['views'];
        }

        mysql_query("UPDATE `$database1`.`memes` SET `views_day` = '0', `views_week` = '$week', `views_month` = '$month' WHERE `meme_id` = '$row[meme_id]' LIMIT 1");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$database2`.`daily_meme_stats` SET `meme_id` = '$row[meme_id]', `date` = '$date'");
    }
?>
```

`update-chars.php`

```
<?php
    // set_time_limit(0);

    include '../config/config.inc.php'; 
    include '../includes/meme-function.php';

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `character_id` FROM `$database1`.`characters`");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $query_b = mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `$database2`.`daily_char_stats` WHERE `char_id` = '$row[character_id]' ORDER BY `date` DESC");

        $c=0; $week=0; $month=0;   

        while($row_b=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_b)) { 
            if($c<=5) {
                $week=$week+$row_b['images'];
            }
            $month=$month+$row_b['images'];
        }

        mysql_query("UPDATE `$database1`.`characters` SET `images_today` = '0', `images_week` = '$week', `images_month` = '$month' WHERE `character_id` = '$row[character_id]' LIMIT 1");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$database2`.`daily_char_stats` SET `char_id` = '$row[character_id]', `date` = '$date'");
    }
?>
```

Btw: I dropped `$minute = date("i"); //  if($minute=='00') {`. No clue, if you really need it.

**Cron**

Add these lines to your cronjobs (adjust paths):

```
# run stats scripts every hour
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/somewhere/update-memes.php
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/somewhere/update-chars.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried splitting the file into two as suggested above but trying to run either returns a gateway timeout error. I have also tried readding the dropped lines but that still doesn't help. Regards

Comment: A gateway timeout error? You tried to run this via the webserver, right? This will not work via a webserver, unless you can modify the timeout value. Did you try running both scripts as cronjobs: `00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/somewhere/update-chars.php`? The cronjobs execute PHP in CLI mode, there is no gateway involved.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestions and ideas and I apologize for the delay in responding as I was giving it some time to run the cron and see if any updates were being made. I have attempted that command line but it seems it doesn't work with /local/ in the path. According to HG support I should use either that same path without /local/ or an /opt53 path (i set the php version for the cron folder to 5.3). I don;t believe the opt53 worked as the timeline of the error log only appeared when using the /usr/bin path

Comment: Btw, I am running the cron for both the old compunded cron job and the new split files to see if one would go through. The new files have not returned any errors but it seems the old cron.php file has returned the same error [20-Jun-2015 03:41:33 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home4/awidaa/mh2/cron/cron.php on line 12 None of them are seeming to update popular images. I have added some more information to the comments above btw. Kindest regardss and thanks for your suggestions thus far.

Comment: Sorry the opt path I was using was /opt/php53/bin/php /path

Comment: I hope the new split files work. And big sorry, i should have used a generic path: `/path/to/php`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I greatly appreciate it. I have disabled and re-enabled the module and it seems the popular images module is now doing what it's supposed to. I'm not sure which of the many cron jobs is doing the right job but I think I'll leave as is for now and keep you updated. Kindest Regards